# Chef for Windows, Gaurd examples for deploying only changes

Tags: chef-infra

I am looking for some examples on how to program guards to achieve differential deployments. Suppose I have exe1, exe2, sql1, sql2 as my entire application. I create a complete cookbooks with steps to deploy the entire application. Deploy it on my servers.

Then I make a change in sql2. I make changes in the cookbook and upload that; the complete cookbook goes up to the server. Now I want chef to do needed deployment steps for sql2 ONLY. Does chef automatically handle that? I see examples where guards are written, e.g. check for DB instance existence, if not install, etc. Do I have to write guards similar to that to check for file changes and deploy only on changes? What are the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

Most Chef resources (and similar constructs in other modern CM tools) are "idempotent" meaning they only take whatever action is required to reach the desired end state. This means if you have, say, a `template` resource and the content is already correct, it doesn't get updated. Some resources can't be idempotent on their own by nature, mostly `execute` and friends, so you can write extra checks to ensure idempotence yourself.

Comment: Looking at the examples in Chef tutorials, this DOES NOT seem to be true. Examples are littered with checks that one has to write oneself. Like install IIS only if not installed, create DB if one is not created. I assume that the examples were written to illustrate that one has to program idempotency.

Comment: I should also clarify that idempotent means that doing the same operation multiple time does not change the state/result etc. Redeploying DB on a running server cannot certainly be made idempotent; unless you happen to have no data in the server. Similarly some scripts cannot be run again and again, without changing the state/result.  The Chef examples clearly demonstrate and take pains to point out how one has to go about putting in appropriate guards.

Comment: A lot of the tutorials are not aimed at producing especially good Chef code. The `windows_feature` resource which is used to install IIS is already internally idempotent because it can check the list of installed features in the registry to see if it needs to run the install on each converge. As I said, some resources aren't idempotent so you do need to write your own guards or ensure the commands being run are idempotent themselves.

Comment: Exactly; that resource has written checks, i.e. written guards, to prevent IIS reinstallation. My question was is there any general purpose guards for common situations like run/copy a file only if changed. Some example code etc. Best practices. That is the idea of a platform; isn't it? That it provides easy way to do common things with minimal coding.